# Reveal all five equations

Tags: formation-of-numbers

Five men enter a bar.

- 1st man order 1 Pepsi and 1 Cocacola
- 2nd man order 2 Pepsi and 1 Cocacola
- 3rd man order 3 Pepsi and 1 Cocacola
- 4th man order 4 Pepsi and 1 Cocacola
- 5th man order 5 Pepsi and 1 Cocacola

But the bar runs out of Pepsi and Cocacola.

To avoid the customers' disappointement, the bartender comes up with a solution.
He gives each man a glass of cocktail, and explains :

> If each letter represents a digit, we can write it like this :
>
> 1 pepsi + 1 cocacola = 1 cocktail
>    or
>    2 pepsi + 1 cocacola = 1 cocktail
>     or
>    3 pepsi + 1 cocacola = 1 cocktail
>     or
>    4 pepsi + 1 cocacola = 1 cocktail
>     or
>    5 pepsi + 1 cocacola = 1 cocktail

After hearing the bartender's explanation, the five men accept his reason, and they are all happy about this mathematical reasoning.

Your task :

Reveal all five math equations !

Comment: Can I ask, did you mean to switch the numbers? So, should "1 pepsi + 2 cocacola = 1 cocktail" be instead "2 pepsi + 1 cocacola = 1 cocktail"?

Comment: I have edited the question, thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure I get it right.
If our task is to give a distinct one-digit numerical value to all the letters so that all the equations hold, then this might work (although not the only solution - there are 2x2x3!x3!x3x3!=2592 of them, I won't post them all):

> a=9; c=8; e=2; i=4; k=3; l=7; o=1; p=0; s=5; t=6

Then

> pepsi $=0\times2\times0\times5\times4=0$
>  cocacola $=8\times1\times8\times9\times8\times1\times7\times9=290304$
>  cocktail $=8\times1\times8\times3\times6\times9\times4\times7=290304$
>  So, no matter how many times you add pepsi (0) to the cocacola (290304), it still remains cocktail (290304).

However, if my interpretation of products is wrong, and @Marius has the good approach with concatenation, then the possible answers are these:

> ```
> n pepsi cocacola cocktail
> 1 42497  6010681  6053178
> 1 24296  8010871  8035167
> 1 26294  8010851  8037145
> 1 47492  6010631  6058123
> 1 40497 26212681 26253178
> 1 43489 27212701 27256190
> 1 42489 37313701 37356190
> 1 20296 48414871 48435167
> 1 20294 68616851 68637145
> 1 40492 76717631 76758123
> 1 75781  4020432  4096213
> 1 34378 19121902 19156280
> 1 31378 49424902 49456280
> 1 70781 54525432 54596213
> 1 19183 70727052 70746235
> 1 17183 90929052 90946235
> 1 51563  8040874  8092437
> 1 50563 18141874 18192437
> 1 15123 46474607 46489730
> 1 14123 56575607 56589730
> 2 15192 76707640 76738024
> 2  4083 69616971 69625137
> 2  6089 52535213 52547391
> 2 27264 58535813 58590341
> 2  6097 12141284 12153478
> 2  8021 34353475 34369517
> 3  4078 39313951 39326185
> 3 20239 54515481 54576198
> 3 27204 65616531 65698143
> 3 26204 85818531 85897143
> 3 12176 80858035 80894563
> 4 18153 64606420 64679032
> 4 10179 35323582 35364298
> 4 10173 85828542 85869234
> 4  8014 52535293 52567349
> 4 10137 59545924 59586472
> 4  7069 43454315 43482591
> 4  1028 94959475 94963587
> 4  7013 45464586 45492638
> 4  3071 45484528 45496812
> 5 12149 73707350 73768095
> 5 13169 82808250 82874095
> 5  7015 42434283 42469358
> 5  1075 69636983 69642358
> ```
>
> Where n stands for which equation we are referring to: n pepsi + 1 cocacola = 1 cocktail.
>  I posted answers which have leading zeros, if those are considered invalid, just neglect them.
>  I did not come up with these manually, used a few lines of python code to get them:
>  
> `import itertools as it
> for n in range(1,6):
>   for (a,c,e,i,k,l,o,p,s,t) in it.permutations(range(10)):
>     pepsi = 10100*p+1000*e+10*s+i
>     cocacola = 10101000*c+1000100*o+10001*a+10*l
>     cocktail = 10100000*c+1000000*o+10000*k+1000*t+100*a+10*i+l
>     if n*pepsi+cocacola==cocktail:
>       print '{0:1d} {1:5d} {2:8d} {3:8d}'.format(n, pepsi, cocacola, cocktail)`

Comment: Amazing, What I expected is the answer like marius, but you came with another good answer (reasoning).

Answer (score 6):

Partial Answer:

I'll start with the last one because it looks easier:

> ```
>     PEPSI +
>
>     PEPSI +
>
>     PEPSI +
>
>     PEPSI +
>
>     PEPSI +
>
>  COCACOLA =
>
>  COCKTAIL
> ```
>
> Because COC is repeated in the last line and in the result it means that P has to be 1. Otherwise we cat a carry from the 10 thousands place and the sum breaks.

Now we have:

> ```
>     1E1SI +
>
>     1E1SI +
>
>     1E1SI +
>
>     1E1SI +
>
>     1E1SI +
>
>  COCACOLA =
>
>  COCKTAIL
> ```

Other restrictions.

> A <= 4 because of the same reason as above.
>  I is odd, otherwise A = L ($5*I + A$ would end in A).
>  From the above we conclude that $L = A+5$
>  This immediately results $E=0$ (otherwise we get a carry) and A not being 4 because it will result in $K=L=9$.
>  Continuing with $A = 3$.  This means $L = 8$
>  now we have
>
> ```
>     1E1SI +
>
>     1E1SI +
>
>     1E1SI +
>
>     1E1SI +
>
>     1E1SI +
>
>  COC3CO83 =
>
>  COCKT3I8
> ```
>
> E can be either 0 or 2 so we won't get on the thousands column a carriage over 2 that will lead in a carriage on the 10thousands column.
>  but for $E = 0$ would result in $K = 8$ but $L = 8$ already. So $E = 2$

Now we have :

> ```
>     121SI +
>
>     121SI +
>
>     121SI +
>
>     121SI +
>
>     121SI +
>
>  COC3CO83 =
>
>  COC9T3I8
> ```
>
> based on the conclusions above trying with $i=5$ we get $S = 7$ and we reach a contradiction later because we either get $C=K=9$ ($T = S = 7$).
>  Following the same logic we can disprove that A can be 2.
>  So we end up with $A = 0$

Now we have:

> ```
>     1E1SI +
>
>     1E1SI +
>
>     1E1SI +
>
>     1E1SI +
>
>     1E1SI +
>
>  COC0CO50 =
>
>  COCKT0I5     (L = 5 because I is odd)
> ```

Further on:

> Trying the possible values 3,7,9 for $I$, I ended up with 2 solutions:
>
> ```
>     12149 +
>
>     12149 +
>
>     12149 +
>
>     12149 +
>
>     12149 +
>
>  73707350 =
>
>  73768095
> ```
>
> And
>
> ```
>     13169 +
>
>     13169 +
>
>     13169 +
>
>     13169 +
>
>     13169 +
>
>  82808250 =
>
>  82874095
> ```

That's it for now. I will try an other equation later.

Comment: great work on equations. +1